# Why can I not access the second level of this array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following array which is passed from an API call from a PHP Script:

```
["playerForm": {
1 =     (
            {
        date = "2017-01-31";
        name = Dicky;
        result = L;
        "results_id" = 42;
    },

            {
        date = "2016-12-24";
        name = Dicky;
        result = W;
        "results_id" = 19;
    }
);
2 =     (
            {
        date = "2017-01-25";
        name = G;
        result = W;
        "results_id" = 38;
    },
            {
        date = "2017-01-25";
        name = G;
        result = D;
        "results_id" = 40;
    },    
            {
        date = "2017-01-21";
        name = G;
        result = L;
        "results_id" = 34;
    }
);
3 =     (
            {
        date = "2017-01-31";
        name = Sultan;
        result = W;
        "results_id" = 42;
    },

            {
        date = "2017-01-15";
        name = Sultan;
        result = L;
        "results_id" = 30;
    }
);
}]
```

However I cannot seem to access the 1,2,3 parts of it...

```
 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                    if let dict = json?["playerForm"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                        print ("step 1")
                        if let arr = dict["1"] as? [[String:String]] {


                            print ("step 2")

                            self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }
                            print (self.leagueForm)
                            print (self.leagueForm.count)

                            for i in 0..<self.leagueForm.count {
                                let form = self.leagueForm[i]
                                print (form.player_results!)
                                self.formGuide.append(form.player_results!)

                            }

                            print ("now")
                            print (self.formGuide)
                            self.resultsDisplay.results = self.formGuide
                            self.resultsDisplay.results = self.resultsDisplay.results.reversed()
                            self.resultsDisplay.displayResults()

                        }

                    }
```

With this code above it only gets as far as Step 1.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATED WITH PROGRSS***

```
  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                    if let dict = json?["playerForm"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                        print ("step 1")

                        for (_ , value) in dict {
                            if let arr = value as? [[String:Any]] {
                                print(arr)
                                //your code
                            }
                        }


                    }
```

Custom Struct to define array:

```
struct Form {
    var player_result: String?
    var player_name: String?
    var result_date: String?
    var result_id: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.player_result = dictionary["result"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player_name = dictionary["name"]  as? String ?? ""
        result_date = dictionary["date"]  as? String ?? ""
        result_id = String(dictionary["results_id"]  as? Int ?? 0)

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your array type `[[String:String]]` to `[[String:Any]]` because it contains both `String` and `Number` as value.

```
if let arr = dict["1"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    print(arr)
    //your code
}
```

**Note:** You need to loop through the `dict` Dictionary because its each key having array.

```
for (_ , value) in dict {
    if let arr = value as? [[String:Any]] {
         print(arr)
         //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That is printing the array 'arr'.  However this line is now erring, which i was using to extract the array:  self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0 ) }

Comment: @RDowns change the init method of `Form` with parameter type to `[String:Any]` instead of `[String:String]`

Comment: @RDowns `results_id` is Int so get as `Int` then convert it to String if you have declared it as a string in your custom class.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Nirav, I have my array printing inside of the for loop.  So now I just need to try and split it up now.  Do i still use flatMap?

Comment: @RDowns Don't get your above comment but you are using `flatMap` to create with custom class object from array of dictionary so you need to do that.

Comment: yes sorry, that wasn't explained very well by me.  So in my limited knowledge I believe I need to use flatMap to create a custom class object from array of dictionary so that I can then display results in a UITable for example.  I have updated my question to show this new custom class.  Am I on the right lines?

Comment: @RDowns I have edited your class in your question, Now it is works with dictionary type `[String:Any]` Check the edit of your question